# What does "complete event for unknown container id" mean in hadoop logs?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a simple job (wordcount example) on multiple files in my cluster but most of maps get failed. When I refer to task logs, I just see error like this:

```
ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Container complete event for unknown container id container_1388066512888_0001_01_000026
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE:** I checked the job many times and sometimes it failed due to map failure, sometimes due to reduce failure and in rare cases it finished successfully. But in any situation, the only error was the above error.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same error:

```
ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator]
```

org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Container complete event for unknown container id container_1406174606649_0001_01_000154

It may related to mapred.child.java.opts property in mapred-site.xml.

I had it like this:

```
<property>
   <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
   <value>
     -Xmx4096M
   </value>
 </property>
```

When I remove this property the error is gone.

Comment: I didn't have it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check both AM and RM side of log for that container to know the actual status of what happened.

**My guess is your nodes are having some kind of communication issue, at least on some vital ports.**

AM tried to ask for container container_1388066512888_0001_01_000026, request went through to RM, but RM didn't respond with the request as it was suppose to.
Resulting in AM thinking container was not allocated by RM probably due to no more resource available.

But since the RM had actually allocated the container, it process it's job and returns the response. Resulting in "unknown container", because from it's perspective that container was never allocated and is unknown.